# How do i remove duplicates data from api

Tags: javascript, fetch

Im fetching data from sportsdata.io and I get all of the data out of it but some of the data is the same becuse of the team names, so how can I remove duplicates and it I only want to get it ones

My code

```js
  fetch(
    // `https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/csgo/scores/json/MembershipsByTeam/100000078?key=${key}`
    `https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/csgo/scores/json/ActiveMemberships?key=${key}`
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      const teamTemplate = document.getElementById("teamTemplate");
      const list = document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0];
      var TeamName = data.map(function (data) {
        return [
          data.TeamName,
          data.PlayerName,
          data.StartDate,
          data.EndDate,
          data.TeamArea,
        ];
      });
      TeamName.sort(data.TeamName);

      if (TeamName[0].includes(TeamName[0]) !== TeamName[0]) {
        console.log(TeamName[0], TeamName[1], "hej");
      }

      console.log(TeamName);
      TeamName.forEach(function (team) {
        const clone = teamTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
        clone.querySelector(".team__name").innerHTML = team[0];
        clone.querySelector(".team__Player-name").innerHTML = team[1];
        clone.querySelector(
          ".team__Player-startDate"
        ).innerHTML = team[2].substr(0, 11);
        if (team[3] !== null) {
          clone.querySelector(".team__Player-startDate").innerHTML = team[3];
        }
        clone.querySelector(".team__Player-teamArea").innerText = team[4];
        list.appendChild(clone);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

[Image of data from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S929u.jpg)

And i only need one of every team

Comment: You want only the first player for every team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the same structure, but only keep the first player for every team, you could use an object to store the team you already encounter and then loop through the array to filter it:

```js
const teamPassed = {}

TeamName = TeamName.filter(playerData => {
  if (teamPassed[playerData[0]]) return false
  teamPassed[playerData[0]] = true
  return true
})
```